# This Query Doesn't Work in a MySQL Stored Procedure, but Works Fine Otherwise

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My query works fine in Workbench:

```
select @sql := `query` from `resultado` where `idregistracion` = 10000030 limit 1;
select @sql;
prepare stmt from  @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

But it doesn't work in a MySQL stored procedure:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists run_queries$$
create procedure run_queries(IN idRegistracion bigint)
begin
    select idRegistracion;
    select @sql := `query` from `resultado` where `idregistracion` = 10000030 limit 1;
    prepare stmt from  @sql;
    execute stmt;
    deallocate prepare stmt;
end$$
```

When I try to execute the call

```
call run_queries(10000030);
```

MySQL gives me this error message:

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1

Anybody know why?

I use MySQL Workbench 6.3, MySQL 5.1.53-community-log, thanks for your advise!

Comment: Did you commit before running the procedure?

Comment: What is in @sql when you prepare it? _Also, (1) what is the point of `select idRegistracion;`, and (2) did you mean for 10000030 to be hardcoded in the proc?_

Comment: Don't use the same name for a procedure parameter as a table column.

Comment: @Uueerdo: select idRegistracion is for only monitoring the parameter... and the harcode id is for the parameter is not able inside de SP (!?), but the problem it isn't. For any reason, cause, the result string from `query` field have, according to workbench, a sintax error...

Comment: @Barmar: mysql code is case sensitive. idRegistracion is the same idregistracion? (Name of field in the table). Is this so?

Comment: @Barmar: is that! The parameter must not has the same name of a table field!!! I'm a donkey! Thanks!!!

Comment: @DanielCorrea Column names are case-insensitive. Table names are case-sensitive if the filesystem is case-sensitive. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html